# How to select item from dropdown element in Javascript

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, javascript

This is the statement i am using in Newrelic synthetic monitor written in javascript

```
return $browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.name("//*[@class=\`attribute-field-container\`]/select//option[5]"), DefaultTimeout); })
```

[image: UI]

Comment: Is there any error message? Probably you will need to firstly click on the dropdown itself and afterwards click on the option, as an user would do. I can transform this comment in a answer if confirmed.

Comment: Try to change all occurrences of ` to `'`